# Hover for different items from legend in Bokeh multiline chart

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

How can I create a hoover for a Bokeh multiline graph where the hover shows data only for the current line?
Example:
I have line1 and line2.
When I hover over line1 I want to see:

Values: values

Line: name of the line

[image]

Here is my code:
graph:

```
fig2 = figure(x_range=x, y_range=[0, 1], plot_width=1500, 
plot_height=600)
line1_2 = fig2.line(x, churn_40d_12m_all, color='blue', line_width=2)
circle1_2 = fig2.circle(x, churn_40d_12m_all, color='blue')
line2_2 = fig2.line(x, churn_40d_12m_b2b, color='brown', line_width=2)
circle2_2 = fig2.circle(x, churn_40d_12m_b2b, color='brown')
line3_2 = fig2.line(x, churn_40d_12m_b2c, color='green', line_width=2)
circle3_2 = fig2.circle(x, churn_40d_12m_b2c, color='green')
line4_2 = fig2.line(x, churn_40d_6m, color='red', line_width=2)
circle4_2 = fig2.circle(x, churn_40d_6m, color='red')
fig2.xaxis.axis_label = 'Month'
fig2.xaxis.major_label_orientation= math.pi/2
fig2.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20px"
fig2.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20px"
fig2.yaxis.axis_label = 'Values'
fig2.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0%")
fig2.add_tools(hover)
fig2.add_layout(Legend(), 'right')
legend2 = Legend(items=[
    ("Line1", [line1_2, circle1_2]),
    ("Line2", [line2_2, circle2_2]),
    ("Line3", [line3_2, circle3_2]),
    ("Line4", [line4_2, circle4_2]),
], location="top_right")
fig2.add_layout(legend2, 'right')
legend2.click_policy = 'hide'
legend2.title="MultilineChart1"
legend2.title_text_font_size = "20px"
legend2.title_text_font_style = "bold"
legend2.label_text_font_size = "15px"
tab2 = Panel(child=fig2, title="MultiLineChart1")
```

Hover code:

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ('Values', '@y{0.00 %}'),
    ('Line', 'name of the current line')
])
```

Thank you!

Comment: please provide your code!

Comment: I have updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find a solution for this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y1=churn_3d_12m_all, y2=churn_3d_6m))
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(tooltips=[
    ('Вид чърн', '$name'),
    ('процент чърн', '$y{0.00 %}')
])

for name in ("y1", "y2"):
    p.line("x", name, source=source, name=name)

output_file("fig1.html")
show(p)
```